# Warning: An update to Component inside a test was not wrapped in act

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm testing my component with Jest and Enzyme but it fails despite following [this article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning) to use `act` method.

#### Error:

```
~ Warning: An update to Component inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
      
~ When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
/* assert on the output */

This ensures that you're testing the behaviour the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act
    in Component (created by WrapperComponent)
    in WrapperComponent

● Component › should render

expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "data"
    Received: "loading"
```

#### Component and it's test:

```js
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import * as React from 'react';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

const getData = async () => new Promise<string>((resolve) => resolve('data'));

const Component: React.FC = () => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState('');
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);

    const onClick = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);

        try {
            const dataResponse = await getData();
            setData(dataResponse);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('getData failed', error);
        }

        setIsLoading(false);
    };

    return (
        <button onClick={onClick}>
            <p>{isLoading ? 'loading' : data}</p>
        </button>
    );
};

describe('Component', () => {
    it('should render', () => {
        const component = mount(<Component />);
        const button = component.find('button');
        const paragraph = component.find('p');

        expect(button).toBeDefined();
        expect(paragraph).toBeDefined();
        expect(paragraph.props().children).toBe('loading');

        void act(() => {
            button.simulate('click');
        });

        expect(paragraph.props().children).toBe('data');
        // test fails here ---------------------^^^^^^
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the `button.simulate`

//something like this

```
await act(async () => {
      button.simulate('click');
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0)); // wait for state update
    });
```

Comment: Throws error: `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.`